# Android Notification Using FCM

Tags: android

I'm having an issue with data from the notification when the app is killed data the data which is sent from intent is getting null else if when the app is running I'm able to see the data.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
//you can use your launcher Activity insted of SplashActivity, But if the Activity you used here is not launcher Activty than its not work when App is in background.
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//Add Any key-value to pass extras to intent
        intent.putExtra("pushnotification", "yes");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
//For Android Version Orio and greater than orio.
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel("Sesame", "Sesame", importance);
            mChannel.setDescription(messageBody);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});

            mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
//For Android Version lower than oreo.
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Seasame");
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_custom_notification)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFD600"))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setChannelId("Sesame")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW);

        mNotifyManager.notify(getRandomId(), mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: This code doesn't work when app is killed. So "pushnotification"  always be null

Comment: so how can it be done @Kasim

Comment: You need to change notification request body

Answer (score 5):

Change your request body this like:

```
{ 
"data":{
    "title" : "your_title",
    "body" : "your_body" 
}, 
  "to": "device_token",
  "priority": "high" 
}
```

and onMessageReceived:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        sendNotification(title,body); // edit for your self
    }
}
```

now it works when app killed, background and foreground