# How to handle FCM data message in background and run a function

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I was working on android FCM data message from a custom server via postman 
I need to execute a task (say upload a file or run some function or anything sort) when a specially crafted data payload arrives eg:
`{"COMMAND":"Upload"}`

As soon as this command is received it need to execute that task in background 
any idea how to do it?
Server working fine notification arrives perfectly

Comment: You can look my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60781500/8956604)

Answer (score 0):

When the messages arrives, use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) to start a task that can be safely managed in the background by Android.