# FCM is not working when the app is killed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am using fcm to puch notification in my app but when the app is closed and cleared from recent apps then notification is not coming.I ma using FCM api to send notification to a particular topic.
Note:- When the app is in background the notification is working fine

This is my FirebaseMessagingService Code

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    Map<String, String> extraData = remoteMessage.getData();

 Log.d("DATA",remoteMessage.getData().toString());

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "TAC")
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);





    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    int id =  (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("TAC","demo",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    notificationManager.notify(id,notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

}

this is Notification Sender class code

public class NotificationSender {

```
public  static RequestQueue mRequest;
public static String URL="https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

public static void sendnotification(Context context,String sendto, String title, JSONObject extra){
    mRequest = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    JSONObject mainbody = new JSONObject();
    try {
        mainbody.put("to","/topics/"+sendto);
          mainbody.put("priority","high");
        JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
        notification.put("title","New Notification");
        notification.put("body",title);
        mainbody.put("notification",notification);
          //  mainbody.put("data",extra);
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("key",title);
            mainbody.put("data",data);


        JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, mainbody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> header = new HashMap<>();
                header.put("content-type","application/json");
                header.put("authorization","key=AIzaSyAfZqD0MW39WIGRBDFG0si3-HszFA");
               // AIzaSyAfZqD0MW39WIu9pWraYA0AG0si3-HszFA
                return header;
            }
        };
        mRequest.add(request);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }






}
```

}

And This is my code to turn off battery optimization

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent();
        final String packageName = getPackageName();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
            AlertDialog ad= new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("IMPORTANT").setMessage("For The Proper Working Of The App,Please Disable Battery Optimization For This App").setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finishAffinity();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }).create();
            ad.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can look the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60781500/8956604). I explained there.

Comment: Sir then also its not working

Comment: Your mainbody contains notification tag. It is not working this way when app killed

Comment: so what should i change

Comment: You should remove notification. You just need to send data

Comment: i removed the "notification" tag now i am only sending data then also its not working                     mainbody.put("to","/topics/"+sendto);
            mainbody.put("priority","high");
            JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
            notification.put("title","New Notification");
            notification.put("body",title);
            mainbody.put("data",notification);

Comment: Yes I added an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many Chinese manufacturers kill the app's background services for saving battery. The running of your notification service is primary to receive push notifications.
However, if you can remove your app from battery optimization in Settings, you'll receive push notifications when your app is in the background or you've killed the app.
This might look like its silly, but when I had the same issue I removed my app from battery optimization and it worked!

Comment: sir i have already turned off battery optimization.I have also posted the code for same

Comment: Did you check in the Settings to see whether the code has removed your app from battery optimization?

Comment: There is a problem due to thecode the app ask to turn off  battery optimization  when I click turn off but then also it doesn't turn off my battery optimisation  .But in some phone it's working after turning off it manually I am getting notifications Can you please share code to do it through program

Comment: I don't think it is related. Even though I turn on the optimization, VOIP apps still work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
mainbody.put("to","/topics/"+sendto);
mainbody.put("priority","high");
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data("title","New Notification");
data("body",title);
mainbody.put("data",data);
```

and

```
Map<String, String> extraData = remoteMessage.getData();

String title = extraData.get("title");
String body = extraData.get.get("body");
```

Comment: Its not working when the app is killed i am using oneplus 7 and also battery optimization is off

Comment: sir i just copy pasted your code in my app but the problem exists

Comment: Sorry, I am asking you check your code again. You may be missing something.

Comment: You are right. There is no problem. Can you check, is it receiving notification when app foreground

Comment: I cannot understand, I am using this method for many years. There is something wrong. It can be "topic"?

Comment: if the topic is wrong then how i am getting notification when the app is not completely killed

Comment: No, Maybe @Mayur is right. But what he says is just for sleep mode

Comment: what I say , I always send to token. I have never sent to topic.