# Android: Receive Firebase Cloud Message when App is killed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

i couldn't find a way to receive Firebase Cloud Message when App is killed.

I am showing push notification with the following code.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) { }
```

Of course onMessageReceived is not empty in my code.

The function onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) can't get called when the app is killed.

How can i solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can look the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60781500/8956604)