# Using DownloadManager in FireBaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, android-download-manager

I want to download a pfd file when ever a specific notification is pushed via FCM. 
I have wrote a service which extends `FirebaseMessagingService` and in `onMessageReceived` event after showing the notification I want to download the file. This process only works when application is active when application is in background it does not work.

Is this because of a restriction or you need a work around to achieve this?
Basic Idea is to send a push notification with a URL in it and accessing the URL in onMessageReceived will download a file from web server. Even if the application is stopped/ in background.

Here is the code.

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

        downloadPdf("www.dummmy.file/file.pdf");
    }
public void downloadPdf(String url) {
        DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
        request.setTitle("My File");
        request.setDescription("Downloading");
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"downloadfileName");

        downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
    }
```

Comment: It is working. May be file url is invalid.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir sorry I forget to mention some details please take a look on update question.

Comment: Your payload json only have to include data. if you send notification : {tittle: ""} , doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60781500/8956604